# ionic commands not working as expected

Tags: ionic-framework

When I run the below commands, instead of starting the emulator and displaying the app I get NO feedback from the prompt:

```
SMV:firstIonicApp$ ionic platform add ios
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Platform ios already added.
SMV:firstIonicApp $ ionic build ios
SMV:firstIonicApp  $ ionic emulate ios
SMV:firstIonicApp $
```

I am running node v4.1.0 along with the following installed globally:

```
├── bower@1.5.2
├── cordova@5.3.1
├── firebase-tools@1.2.0
├── flightplan@0.6.4
├── gulp@3.9.0
├── ionic@1.6.4
├── ios-sim@5.0.1
├── node-inspector@0.10.2
├── npm@2.14.1
└── pm2@0.14.3



Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.8
ios-deploy version: 1.7.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v4.1.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.0 Build version 7A220
```

Comment: do u have ios-sim installed?

Comment: Do u have xcode installed?

Comment: installed it after you mentioned .. still no emulator launches

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved a day later using the following steps:

1. Remove node v 4.0
   ( used the following steps to achieve it
   https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef
   Thankfully none of my other programs broke when I performed these steps
   )
2. Install node v0.10.9